# How to check if a point lies on the (minimum) manhattan distance line?

Tags: python, python-3.x, distance

I have an 8x10 matrix with some squares blocked out in it:

```
no = [(2,4),(3,4),(6,4),(7,4),(2,5),(3,5),(6,5),(7,5)]
```

And I need to figure out if the shortest (manhattan) path between two points, given to this function as a nested tuple like ((0,5),(6,2)), contains any block, and re-route around it.

Now to do this, I was trying to apply the logic that works for euclidean distance that to see if *C* is on the line between *A* and *B* by adding the distance from *A* to *C* to the distance from *C* to *B* and seeing if it equals *A* to *B*, but I don't trust the math...

```
def manhattan_dist(move): #order doesn't matter
    a = move[0][0]
    b = move[0][1]
    c = move[1][0]
    d = move[1][1]
    mandist = abs(a-c)+abs(b-d)

    if (any (abs(a-box[0])+abs(b-box[1])) == (mandist-(abs(c-box[0])+abs(d-box[1]))) for box in no):
        print("blocked")
        #calculate go-around logic

    return mandist
```

It prints "blocked" for `manhattan_dist(((0,1),(0,7)))`, so I know I'm doing something wrong in the python too.

Comment: "I have an 8x10 matrix with some squares blocked out in it:" What do you mean by "some squares blocked out"? Do you mean that no path can go through any point with the given coordinates in the list `no`?

Answer (score 1):

Answering instead of commenting due to lacking of rep (...I'm new here).
Seems to me a little ill-defined. The manhattan distance doesn't have a single shortest route...In fact it by definition has many shortest paths.
So maybe try clarify what you meant?

BTW, if you want to know if *any* of the manhattan paths are blocked, then that just means you have a box with

```
min([a, c]) < box[0] < max([a, c]) and min([b, d]) < box[1] < max([b, d])
```

---

Edit due to discussion in comments:
First of all, there are always exactly `abs(a-c) + abs(b-d)` *choose* `abs(a-c)` paths with the minimal manhattan distance. (Sorry for the bad notation; just following the questions params and unfortunately lacking latex support).
If you go through the geometry properly, *all* minimal path being blocked is pretty tricky and won't be fast. I don't off-hand see a way of avoiding looping through all paths, with some optimization gained via sorting the paths into a hierarchical tree and removing full branches when a square is blocked...

Comment: In some situations, there is only one, and it will take you through these squares. As in, in this situation, the distance from 2,2 to 5,3 has a distance of four only if you go through the closed up square

Comment: going from 2, 2 to 5, 3 is of distance 4 whether you turn "right" at the beginning, end, or middle. So I'm not sure what you mean...

Comment: @CapnShanty I think that will only be true if you are missing connections between some of the intergral coordinates.

Comment: yes but both of those four distance routes go through my blocked out cube

Comment: There are __4__ paths between 2, 2 and 5, 3. But again; do you mean to ask about _all_ paths being blocked?

Comment: Only two of them have a distance of four though; no, just if all the minimum distance paths are

Comment: @CapnShanty All 4 paths that ShlomiF is referring to have distance 4: (2, 2)->(2,3)->(3,3)->(4,3)->(5,3) or (2,2)->(3,2)->(3,3)->(4,3)->(5,3) or (2,2)->(3,2)->(4,2)->(4,3)->(5,3) or (2,2)->(3,2)->(4,2)->(4,3)->(5,3)

Comment: @CapnShanty Of course, I am assuming a complete lattice here. Is there a reason to disqualify any of these 4 paths?

Comment: Note that if you do not have a complete lattice, you can rely on graph theory to still calculate the shortest path between any two points without iterating over all paths with Dijkstra's algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

> Now to do this, I was trying to apply the logic that works for euclidean distance that to see if C is on the line between A and B by adding the distance from A to C to the distance from C to B and seeing if it equals A to B

The mathematical concept you are using here is called a "metric". This is just a generalization of the Euclidean distance which you are already familiar with. For details see [the wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_(mathematics)). The Manhattan distance satisfies all of the requirements of a metric. This means that you can be assured that if `d(A, B) + d(B, C) = d(A, C)` the `B` lies on some shortest path between `A` and `C`. Unlike with Euclidean distance, there may be many paths from `A` to `C` with the same distance and many of these may go through `B`.